# Marmalade Visual Studio Setup

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, marmalade

I was having license errors with the latest Marmalade (6.4) and I reran s3eConfig to fix them.  I set it to use Visual Studio 2010 and it re-setup marmalade and the license errors went away. However it is not respecting my Visual Studio selection and always opens Visual Studio 2012.

So, my question is where does marmalade hide these config values that you set when running s3eConfig? It looks like I will have to change it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Marmalade saves these values in AppData. But instead of modifying these values, you can just right click on the mkb and open them in your desired IDE disregarding the default ones.

I guess the Visual Studio 2012 is the phone version(wp8). Marmalade has a bug regarding this, don't remember the MAINT number/bug issue tracking number.